# Listing the different scaffolds generated in your rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I have generated two scaffold using the following two commands:

```
$:- rails generate scaffold User user:string gender:string
$:- rails generate scaffold Microposts microposts:string
```

Is there any command that will list me the different scaffolds i have generated so far?
It should give me the output similar to this:

```
Scaffold generated:
User
Microposts
```

Comment: You could use version control system to track changes inside your projects.

Comment: Why do you want this list?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but you can see the direct result in your application, plus after each scaffold you see which files are generated. To quote RoR guides:

> A scaffold in Rails is a full set of model, database migration for that model, controller to manipulate it, views to view and manipulate the data, and a test suite for each of the above.

A scaffold in itself is not one thing, it's a collection. What would be the point of only displaying the name you used to scaffold all these files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so - scaffolding generates models, views and controllers for a given class (in your case User and Microposts) - if you look at app/models you'll see `User.rb` and `Microposts.rb`.  So maybe that's nearly the same thing?